# Finding the Power developed by the Nominal Frequency in FM

Tags: power, signal, communication, modulation, wave

**Question**

> The sinusoidal signal \$f(t) = \cos(2 \pi f_m t)\$ is applied to the
>   input of an FM system. The corresponding modulation signal output for
>   \$f_m = 1kHz\$, is
>
> $$Q(t)=100 \cos(2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t + 4 \sin(w \pi 1000t)) \space
> > V$$
>
> across 50 ohm resistive load.
>
> What is the power developed at 100MHz?

**My Work**

\$Q(t) = 100\cos(2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t + 4 \sin(w \pi 1000t))\$
 \$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
       = 100 \cos(2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t) \cos(4 \sin(2 \pi 1000 t))
         - 100 \sin (2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t) \sin(4 sin(2 \pi 1000 t))\$

Where 
 \$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\cos(4 \sin(2 \pi 1000 t) \approx 1\$ and; 
  \$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\sin(4 sin(2 \pi 1000 t)) \approx 4 \sin(2 \pi 1000 t)\$
 
(These relationships are obtained from my lecture note)

Therefore,
 \$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
    Q(t) = 100 \cos(2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t) - 100 \sin (2 \pi 100 \times 10^6 t) \times 4\sin (2 \pi 1000 t)\$

Using equation \$P=\frac{V^2}{2R}\$, \$P\space =\space \frac{100^2}{2\cdot 50}=100\space W\$.

There are two things containing \$100*10^6\$ Hz, I do not know whether it is correct...
Can you explain more about this question to me?

Comment: Which equation is the one "seen" at the antenna?

Comment: The power developed at exactly 100 MHz is zero when modulated with a continuous waveform.

Answer (score 1):

Power developed at 100 MHz can be easily calculated by using Bessel function.

By Bessel function,
J0(4) = -0.4

P= 1/2R * Ac^2 * J0(4)^2
 = 800/R W